# Changing font properties to alter the spacing between characters in a string?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, character, spacing

Does anyone know how i am able (if possible) to change the character spacing of a string or textbox output? One possibility is by creating a custom font, but i am unsure if there is a property in one of the overloads that will allow me to change character spacing?! Any response would be great, thanks in advance guys!

Answer (score 1):

Well, I was going to send you down the path of [CHARFORMAT2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb787883%28VS.85%29.aspx) where you can set the `sSpacing` value but according to that page:

> This value has no effect on the text displayed by a rich edit control;

So basically, I don't think you can, sorry.